# How to inverse-difference time series data?

Tags: r, time-series, data-transformation, lstm, differencing

I'm preparing a time series model with LSTM, I noticed that the time series data is not stationary so I used `diff(period=1)` in `pandas`. I fitted the LSTM model and it looks good. I invert the difference operation using original data. When we are forecasting in real time, how to invert the predictions because the original data is not available?

How I inverse-transformed is

```
pred = model.predict(x_test_diff)
y_test_inv_diff = y_test.shift(1) + y_test_diff
pred = y_test.shift(1) + pred
```

I have the original dataset `y_test`, so I was able to inverse-difference predictions. What to do when I'm making forecasts in real time?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The inverse difference is the cumulative sum of the first value of the original series and the first differences:

```r
y=rnorm(10)    # original series
dy=diff(y)     # first differences
invdy=cumsum(c(y[1],dy)) # inverse first differences
print(y-invdy) # discrepancy between the original series and its inverse first differences
```

There is a tiny discrepancy between the original series and its inverse first differences due to rounding.

Whenever you need to invert differencing (in real time or otherwise), you have to have some value of the original series available (e.g. the first value as in my example); you cannot do without it.

Comment: How would one do for differences of period greater than 1?

Comment: @Anoldmaninthesea., cumulatively sum observations that are $h$ periods apart where $h$ is the period. You would have to do this for $h$ different starting points: observations 1, 2, ..., $h$. Thus you get $h$ series. Then put them together row by row in a matrix and then read the matrix column by column. (Typing from my phone, so the answer is not all that detailed.)

Comment: Thanks Richard, I also thought of that... but then I went with cumulatively summing `inverted_value[i] = diff_value[i]+inverted_value[i-period]` probably yours is faster, but I couldn't find a predefined pandas function for putting them together row by row...

Comment: Forecasting is complex and I am new to it. I feel inverse difference of predictions should be the cumulative sum of last value of original data and the predicted difference series. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @ManishankarSingh, that sounds right. When forecasting, what I called the first value of the original series is the last value of the original data (as you said).

Comment: How can you force your keras model to use the loss function using this "inverse difference"?
Or maybe the model fitted with the differences will also be the best model after inverting diffs?

Comment: @skan, I am not sure what you are asking about. But as I do not use Python, I would probably not be able to answer anyway.

Answer (score 1):

For Python implementation of Richard's answer:

```
x = [0,11,24,37,49,59]
print(x)
z = pm.utils.diff(x,lag=1,differences=1)
print(z)
z = np.insert(z,0,x[0])
print(z)
print(np.cumsum(z))
```